# Does optaweb-employee-rostering support mssql

Tags: optaplanner, optaweb-employee-rostering

I'm just wondering if the app supports mssql.  I found datasource configuration for H2 and PostgreSQL but non for other datasources supported by Quarkus.

Answer (score 2):

Optaweb-employee-rostering is a rich example application that shows how the employee rostering problem can be solved with OptaPlanner. As such, users are expected to take inspiration from it and change the app as they need.

If you want to try the app with MS SQL, replace a JDBC driver dependency:
https://github.com/kiegroup/optaweb-employee-rostering/blob/main/optaweb-employee-rostering-backend/pom.xml#L81-L84

and change the Quarkus profile:
https://github.com/kiegroup/optaweb-employee-rostering/blob/main/optaweb-employee-rostering-backend/src/main/resources/application.properties#L24-L28

The Quarkus profile can be activated during the build by specifying the `quarkus.profile` maven property, e.g.:
`mvn clean install -Dquarkus.profile=postgres`

Comment: When I run the app or the optaweb-employee-rostering-backend, it dynamically creates the H2 database in-memory.  If it's not too much to ask, can you point me to the file(s) that define and create the schema of the database?

Comment: That is defined in the `application.properties` file I provided a link to. Please have a look at my edited answer to see how to switch the DB profiles.

Comment: What I'm actually looking for is how the tables (contract, employee, tenant etc.) and functions of the database were created. Are the tables and functions defined somewhere in the application in some sort of a file (xml, json, etc.) where quarkus is mapped to?  Where?

As always, I appreciate the answers. :)

Comment: The persistence is handled by Hibernate, which is available in the Quarkus ecosystem as an extension [1].
The mapping of domain classes to tables is a part of the domain model [2] in the form of `javax.persistence.*` annotations.

[1] https://quarkus.io/guides/hibernate-orm
[2] https://github.com/kiegroup/optaweb-employee-rostering/tree/main/optaweb-employee-rostering-backend/src/main/java/org/optaweb/employeerostering/domain